# CONVLSTM2D to predict the second image from the first image

Tags: image, keras, lstm

I have sequences of images (2 images in each sequence). I am trying to use CONVLSTM2D to train on this sequence.

Question:
Can I train LSTM model on just 2 images per sequence? The goal would be, prediction of second image from the first image.

Thanks!

Comment: Please give more information about the task and data. What are the images? How are they related to each other?

Answer (score 1):

You can, but is this the best to do? (I don't know either).

I think that using a sequence of two steps won't bring a lot of extra intelligence, it's just an input -> output pair in the end.

You could also simply put one image as input and the other as output in a sort of U-Net.

But many of these things must be tested for our surprise. Maybe the way things are made inside the LSTM, with gates and such could add some interesting behavior?